# How to set default values for GetOpt?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, getopt

I thought it was as easy as:

```
my $man = 0;
my $help = 0;
my @compList = ('abc', 'xyz');
my @actionList = ('clean', 'build');

## Parse options and print usage if there is a syntax error,
## or if usage was explicitly requested.
GetOptions('help|?' => \$help, man => \$man, 'complist:s@' => \@compList, 'action:s@' => \@actionList) or pod2usage(2);
```

However, when I do:

```
script.pl --action clean
```

And I print my `actionList`, it just appends my parameter to the end: `clean build clean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For scalars set the default in the call to GetOptions.  However, for arrays, you'll need to be more explicit with your logic.

```
## Parse options and print usage if there is a syntax error,
## or if usage was explicitly requested.
GetOptions(
    'help|?'       => \(my $help = 0),
    'man'          => \(my $man = 0),
    'complist:s@'  => \my @compList,
    'action:s@'    => \my @actionList,
) or pod2usage(2);

# Defaults for array
@compList = qw(abc xyz) if !@compList;
@actionList = qw(clean build) if !@actionList;
```

Note, because `$help` and `$man` are just boolean flags, it's not actually necessary to initialize them.  Relying on their default of `undef` works fine unless you're trying to print their values out somewhere.

Comment: Thanks - I've made your changes, but now I've noticed something else; only one value is saved in the array: `--complist COMPA COMPB` produces only `COMPA`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the defaults after `GetOptions`, like this:

```
my @compList;
GetOptions('complist:s@' => \@compList) or pod2usage(2);
@compList = qw(abc xyz) unless @compList;
```